# knockoutJS activate/deactivate value input

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, data-binding, typescript

few weeks ago I've started to work with typescript and knockoutJS, I have a specific problem and yet I have solution for it, it's so ugly I can't stand that, but can't get anything better from it, there's too much code to be pasted, but i'll try to describe my problem the best I can:

I have two view models that communicate with the same data model. Let's say that model is an array of Simple Objects called Numbers. Every Number has following properties: Value, isMinValueEnabled, minValue, isMaxValueEnabled, maxValue, isStepEnabled, stepValue, valueFormat. valueFormat might be numeric or percentage (so that value, min, max and step are multiplied by 100). I can activate minimum, maximum and step values and deactivate them. Then save data to the model and do exactly the same (with some restrictions) in another viewModel.

The problem is with those optional parameters and percentage values, because when I'm reading data I firstly check if Number is percentage or not and if every property is Enabled. Then I eventually multiply value by 100 if it is set. I have to do the same operation when I'm saving data, that is check every number for format and is*Enabled and eventually divide by 100. With 3-4 properties there is no problem, but now I have to write few more optional properties that depend's on the format and enabled/disabled state and I'm getting into troubles with ton's of if's statements, I myself can't even read that. Is there some better patter that can be used in this situation?

## EDIT

Ok, so things look like this: I have a series of numbers, they can look like:
`100, 2 000, 34 000.21, 2.1k, 2.11M, 22%` but those are only display values whereas real values should stand like this for the example given: `100, 2000, 34000.21, 2100, 2110000, 0.22`. The user can edit the value to anything else, like, let's say has 22% in input and then edit this into 1k. I shall convert 1k to original value which is 1000 and check if minimumValue and maximumValue for that number are set. If they are, I will check, and let's say maxValue is 800, then user input can no longer be 1k, but 0.8k instead because he can not get out of maximumValue. MinimumValue, MaximumValue, StepValue and so on are properties of every single Number. I was playing with ko.pureComputed, but I need to abstract it somehow:

```
var f = ko.computed(<KnockoutComputedDefine<number>>{
            read: ...
            write: ... 
        });
```

What I have now is totally ugly and looks like this:

```
export class Variable {
    [...]
    public inputType: KnockoutObservable<VariableInputType>;
    public typeAndFormat: KnockoutObservable<DataTypeFormat>;
    public isMinEnabled: KnockoutObservable<boolean>;
    public minValue: KnockoutObservable<number>;
    public isMaxEnabled: KnockoutObservable<boolean>;
    public maxValue: KnockoutObservable<number>;
    public isStepEnabled: KnockoutObservable<boolean>;
    public stepValue: KnockoutObservable<number>;
    public value: KnockoutObservable<number>;
    [...]

    constructor(...) {
        [...]
        this.inputType = ko.observable(VariableInputType.Input);
        this.typeAndFormat = ko.observable(variable.typeAndFormat || DataTypeFormat.Number);

        if (variable.minValue !== null) {
            this.isMinEnabled = ko.observable(true);
            this.minValue = ko.observable(variable.minValue);
        } else {
            this.isMinEnabled = ko.observable(false);
            this.minValue = ko.observable(null);
        }
        if (variable.maxValue !== null) {
            this.isMaxEnabled = ko.observable(true);
            this.maxValue = ko.observable(variable.maxValue);
        } else {
            this.isMaxEnabled = ko.observable(false);
            this.maxValue = ko.observable(null);
        }
        if (variable.step !== null) {
            this.isStepEnabled = ko.observable(true);
            this.stepValue = ko.observable(variable.step);
        } else {
            this.isStepEnabled = ko.observable(false);
            this.stepValue = ko.observable(null);
        }
        if (variable.defaultValue !== null) {
            this.value = ko.observable(variable.defaultValue);
        } else {
            this.value = ko.observable(0);
        }

        if (this.typeAndFormat() === DataTypeFormat.NumberPercentage) {
            this.value(this.value() * 100);
            if (this.isMinEnabled()) this.minValue(this.minValue() * 100);
            if (this.isMaxEnabled()) this.maxValue(this.maxValue() * 100);
            if (this.isStepEnabled()) this.stepValue(this.stepValue() * 100);
        }

        [...]

        this.isMinEnabled.subscribe((v) => { if (v !== true) this.minValue(null) }, this);
        this.isMaxEnabled.subscribe((v) => { if (v !== true) this.maxValue(null) }, this);
        this.isStepEnabled.subscribe((v) => { if (v !== true) this.stepValue(null)}, this);
        [...]
    }

    public getModifiedVariable() {
        [...]
        this.originalData.typeAndFormat = this.typeAndFormat();
        this.originalData.minValue = this.minValue();
        this.originalData.maxValue = this.maxValue();
        this.originalData.step = this.stepValue();
        this.originalData.defaultValue = this.value();
        [...]

        if (this.typeAndFormat() === DataTypeFormat.NumberPercentage) {
            this.originalData.defaultValue = this.originalData.defaultValue / 100;
            if (this.isMinEnabled()) this.originalData.minValue = this.originalData.minValue / 100;
            if (this.isMaxEnabled()) this.originalData.maxValue = this.originalData.maxValue / 100;
            if (this.isStepEnabled()) this.originalData.step = this.originalData.step / 100;
        }
        [...]
        return this.originalData;
    };

    [...]
}
```

The second viewmodel that has even more validation and restrictions looks even worse... I don't really know how I could abstract that so that it would be readable for me and for others.

Comment: I can understand you've done a great effort to try to explain the problem,but I'm afraid it's not enough to undertsnad what the problem is. You don't need to include the whole code, but you should add a little example with a few lines of code to explain the problem. There are many things that can be done to solve all kind of problems with ko, like computed observables,templates and many other techniques. Please, add the little code sample and explain a concrete problem using it. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I just found on KO documentation ko.pureComputed with read and write methods, will try to modify my code for that and if it won't fix the problem I'll fine-tune my question

Comment: Computed is one way to deal with the problem, another would be a custom binding handler. Check out http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html on Knockoutjs.com and also http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/07/another-look-at-custom-bindings-for.html

Comment: Oh, and for more complex requirements you might consider using Knockout components

Comment: Hello @JotaBe I updated my question, I believe it's now more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different problems

1. you need a custom visualization, that needs formatting, and a custom data input, that needs parsing
2. you need to add some business logic (validation of values)

The first question can be solved by [using an extender](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html). With this technique your observable must store the actual value, not the formatted value. You can use it to add a child `observable`, which could be called `formattedValue`. This must be a [writable computed observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html), which two functions:

- read: format the underlying actual value, and return it formatted, so that the user has a beautiful view of the value
- write: parse the value received from the user input, and store the result in the underlying actual value

You can find examples of extenders like theses ones: [Three Useful Knockout Extenders](http://newmedialabs.co.za/blog/post/KnockoutExtenders). The extenders can recevie parameters, so that they can be configured individually (in your case you can set percentage, steps, and so on). Another big example of this technique is the [ko.valdiation library](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation).

If you use this technique, in the HTML you need to bind the child observable, instead of the underlying observable with the real value, i.e.:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: vm.someValue.formattedValue"/>
```

As explained, the `formattedValue` is a new child observable which formats/parses the value.

The second question can also be solved with [writable computed observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html). You can add the validation logic in the write method, so that any time the value is modified, it's validated, and rejected or corrected, depending on what you want to do. The computed observable can access other values from the view model, so its implementation should be easy. Of course, the validation logic must access the observables with the actual values. I.e it can completely ignore if the observable is extended or not.

The great advantage of this implementation is that you can implement an test each required functionality independently:

- implement and test the parsing/formatting extenders, the format/parse in the extenders
- implementa and test the the business logic in the writable computed observables

Once implemented an tested, start using them together.